# FileNotFoundError: "pyannote.database"

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, voice-recognition, pyaudio

Currently I am working speaker Diarization on python where I am using pyannote for embedding.
I install pynnote by command:

```
!pip install -q https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio/tarball/develop
```

My embedding function looks like:

```
import torch
import librosa
from pyannote.core import Segment

def embeddings_(audio_path,resegmented,range):
    model_emb = torch.hub.load('pyannote/pyannote-audio', 'emb')
  
    embedding = model_emb({'audio': audio_path})
    for window, emb in embedding:
            assert isinstance(window, Segment)
            assert isinstance(emb, np.ndarray)

    y, sr = librosa.load(audio_path)
    myDict={}
    myDict['audio'] = audio_path
    myDict['duration'] = len(y)/sr

    data=[]
    for i in resegmented:
            excerpt = Segment(start=i[0], end=i[0]+range)
            emb = model_emb.crop(myDict,excerpt)
            data.append(emb.T)
    data= np.asarray(data)
  
    return data.reshape(len(data),512)
```

when I call the function:

```
embeddings = embeddings_(audiofile,resegmented,2)
```

I got this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: "pyannote.database" relies on a YAML configuration file but could not find any. Here are the locations that were looked for: /home/subhash/Untitled Folder/Inpycgam/database.yml, /home/subhash/.pyannote/database.yml.
```

source code:  https://github.com/muskang48/Speaker-Diarization/blob/master/sp_diarization.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

before performing any experiments you have to follow this [one](https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio/tree/develop/tutorials/data_preparation). In this they describe on how to create a config file and tell the interpreter its location so that it can be found during runtime